Error: Received message larger than max (1970303084 vs 67108864). Yellowstone-grpc geyser. NodeJS
I have a locally deployed Solana RPC with the Yellowstone-grpc geyser plugin. When trying to retrieve any data, like this:
import Client from '@triton-one/yellowstone-grpc';

const client = new Client.default('http://127.0.0.1:8899', undefined, {
        'grpc.max_receive_message_length': 64 * 1024 * 1024, // 64MiB
    });

const version = await client.getVersion();

// Any method call on the Client object results in this error
// const stream = await client.subscribe();

I get an error:
Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Received message larger than max (1970303084 vs 67108864)
...
{
  code: 8,
  details: 'Received message larger than max (1970303084 vs 67108864)',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
}

When I increase the value of the property "grpc.max_receive_message_length" the following error is returned:
Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Received HTTP status code 415
...
{
  code: 2,
  details: 'Received HTTP status code 415',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} }
}


solana verison: 1.18.26,
yellowstone-grpc version: v1.18
Why does the response come so big (~2gb) and how can I solve this problem?
